# Which family is it?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> On the 20th of July '19 it's a large family of 175 members that keeps growing. Youngest is only 2 months. Only four of them are more than 10 years old.

What family is it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it is

> the family of all Stack Exchange sites.

Because

> there are [175 of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322796/278659), with [only four more than 10 years old](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#oldest) (actually three because of complicated MSE/MSO history), and [the newest](https://or.stackexchange.com/) is just 2 months old.